# Debug a react-native App that crashes directly after launch

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I am trying to run a [react-native sample project](https://github.com/bobinrinder/react-native-ignite-firebase-kitten-boilerplate). The app is working fine on iOS but not on android. By running `react-native run-android`, the app crashes immediately after the launch. I am not able to identify the problem from the logs

```
2022-02-18 11:32:35.571 6437-6474/com.ignitefirebasekittenboilerplate D/SoLoader: Not resolving dependencies for libfbjni.so
2022-02-18 11:32:35.571 6437-6474/com.ignitefirebasekittenboilerplate D/SoLoader: Loaded: libfbjni.so
2022-02-18 11:32:35.575 6437-6474/com.ignitefirebasekittenboilerplate D/ReactNativeFirebaseApp: received application context.
2022-02-18 11:32:35.576 6437-6437/com.ignitefirebasekittenboilerplate W/ttenboilerplat: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-02-18 11:32:35.577 6437-6437/com.ignitefirebasekittenboilerplate W/ttenboilerplat: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-02-18 11:32:35.582 6437-6467/? V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 6465184
2022-02-18 11:32:35.587 6437-6467/? I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
2022-02-18 11:32:35.591 6437-6474/? E/unknown:ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext: mJSIModulePackage null
2022-02-18 11:32:35.591 6437-6476/? E/ReactNativeJNI: logMarker CREATE_REACT_CONTEXT_END
2022-02-18 11:32:35.592 6437-6474/? E/unknown:DisabledDevSupportManager: Caught exception
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:234)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:29)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:258)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1293)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1100(ReactInstanceManager.java:131)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1016)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
2022-02-18 11:32:35.592 6437-6474/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
    Process: com.ignitefirebasekittenboilerplate, PID: 6437
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:234)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:29)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:258)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1293)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1100(ReactInstanceManager.java:131)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1016)
```

Is the problem here `Not resolving dependencies for libfbjni.so`? I google it and tried all the answers without success. Is it possible to have more detailed logs? Could it be a mac M1 problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native: Unfortunately, Application has stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51389541/react-native-unfortunately-application-has-stopped)

Answer (score 1):

In the android/app/build.gradle

```
 implementation(platform("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.9.0"))
```

https://github.com/tinycreative/react-native-intercom/issues/441